# how does work break statement in inner loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, nested, break

I am new in C language. Please help me.
How does the break statement work between inner loop  & outer loop?
If i use break statement in this case, which loop with be terminated?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main(){
      int arr[67778], i, j, k, min, max, n, count = 0;
      scanf("%s"`enter `enter code here`code here`, &arr);
      n = strlen(arr);
      for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        for(i = 1; i< n; i++){
          if(arr[j] == arr[j]){
            count++;
          }
          else break;
        }
        count = 0;
      }
      if(count >= 6){
        printf("Yes\n");
      }
      else printf("No\n");
   }
```

**By this program, i just want to print "YES" if there 7 inputs are same charcters alongside, else NO should be printed.
please help me**

Comment: `break` only exits the loop, its currently in.

Comment: Code won't compile anyway.

Comment: Is this for the IOCCC?

Comment: You need to go through basic c programming books, also before writing a program be clear with what you need

Comment: Tnx,please, help me in case of getting my desired output  mentioned above.

Comment: A break only exits the block it is in. In your case it will exit the second loop.

Comment: Have you read the warning bcz of this line `scanf("%s",arr);`take `char arr[67778]` instead of `int arr[67778]`

Comment: Please indent your code. It's for your own good.

Comment: That's rather a large array for automatic storage.  Be prepared for your program to overflow its stack.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Post a properly formatted MCVE.

Comment: Also, you should add an exemple of what you want and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your primary question, the `break` function will allow code to break in the midst of a loop, such as `while`, `for`, `until`, and so on. It provides programmers a way to stop their code should a condition be met requiring that loop to stop. `break` only breaks the loop that's currently within scope.

However in practice, the use of break is not advised as there are other loop structures that can accomplish whatever task you seek in a much safer and more understandable way. If you need to stop looping ***while*** in a loop, use a **while** (or until, or something else). Only put breaks in your code if its absolutely necessary, which if you aren't running assembly code, will be *very* few use cases.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

As for the other elephant in the room, C is a language that you can do anything with and it only goes as far as you are willing to get your hands dirty with regards to pointers and memory handling. I **highly** suggest familiarizing yourself with pointers, memory handling, arguments, and overall program design, as the code you originally passed was quite paltry. We all have to write bad code once in our life if we are to become better programmers. Also the following is code that will read input passed to it (at command line) and look for several repeating characters of that passed input.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    // Check to see if no arguments were passed to program. 
    // Remember, argv[0] is the program you are calling
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("You need to specify some input for this to work.\n");
        return; // End program early
    }
    int i = 0; // Loop control
    int count = 0; // Repetitive char count. After init, it will be set to 1
    char check = *(argv[1] + i); // Store the first character to check
    // argument's character not null and char sequence less than 7
    while (*(argv[1] + i) != 0 && count < 7)
    {
        // The last character is the same as the current one
        if (check == *(argv[1] + i))
        {
            count++; // Increment count. 
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1; // Reset count and try again.
            check = *(argv[1] + i); // Store a character to check
        }
        i++;
    }
    char* result = !(count < 7) ? "yes" : "no"; // Boolean for yes or no
    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can someone in the community verify that the reason that `break` is still around is because assembly language still requires it?